# Make Javascript Threads Fast

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Recently I have been trying to use the **Web workers** interface to experiment with threads in JavaScript.

Trying to make **contains** with web workers, following these steps:

- Split the initial array to pieces of equal size
- Create a web worker for each piece that runs **.contains** on that piece
- When and if the value is found in any of the pieces, it returns true without waiting for all workers to finish.

Here is what I tried:

```js
var MAX_VALUE = 100000000;
var integerArray = Array.from({length: 40000000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_VALUE));

var t0 = performance.now();
console.log(integerArray.includes(1));
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

var promises = [];
var chunks = [];
while(integerArray.length) {
    chunks.push(integerArray.splice(0,10000000));
}

t0 = performance.now();
chunks.forEach(function(element) {
    promises.push(createWorker(element));
});

function createWorker(arrayChunk) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var v = new Worker(getScriptPath(function(){
            self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                var value = e.data.includes(1);
                self.postMessage(value);
            }, false);
        }));
        v.postMessage(arrayChunk);
        v.onmessage = function(event){
            resolve(event.data);
        };
    });
}

firstTrue(promises).then(function(data) {
    // `data` has the results, compute the final solution
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
});

function firstTrue(promises) {
    const newPromises = promises.map(p => new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => p.then(v => v && resolve(true), reject)
));
   newPromises.push(Promise.all(promises).then(() => false));
    return Promise.race(newPromises);
}

//As a worker normally take another JavaScript file to execute we convert the function in an URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799132/2576706
function getScriptPath(foo){ return window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([foo.toString().match(/^\s*function\s*\(\s*\)\s*\{(([\s\S](?!\}$))*[\s\S])/)[1]],{type:'text/javascript'})); }
```

Any browser and cpu tried, it is extremely slow compared to just do a simple **contains** to the initial array.

Why is this so **slow**?
What is wrong with the code above?

References

- [Waiting for several workers to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423905/wait-for-several-web-workers-to-finish)
- [Wait for the first true returned by promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160260/clean-way-to-wait-for-first-true-returned-by-promise/51160727#51160727)

Edit: The issue is not about .contains() in specific, but it could be other array functions, e.g. .indexOf(), .map(), forEach() etc. Why splitting the work between web  workers takes much longer...

Comment: Im going to do some more research and post a better comment, but I wonder if this could be caused by slow performance of the native `includes` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a contrived example so it's hard to help optimize for what you're trying to do specifically but one easily-overlooked and fix-able slow path is copying data to the web-worker. If possible you can use ArrayBuffers and SharedArrayBuffers to transfer data to and from web workers quickly.

You can use the second argument to the postMessage function to transfer ownership of an arrayBuffer to the web worker. It's important to note that that buffer will no longer be usable by the main thread until it is transferred *back* by the web worker. SharedArrayBuffers do not have this limitation and can be read by many workers at once but aren't necessarily supported in all browsers due to a security concern (see [mdn for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer))

For example

```
const arr = new Float64Array(new ArrayBuffer(40000000 * 8));

console.time('posting');
ww.postMessage(arr, [ arr.buffer ]);
console.timeEnd('posting');
```

takes ~0.1ms to run while

```
const arr = new Array(40000000).fill(0);

console.time('posting');
ww.postMessage(arr, [ arr ]);
console.timeEnd('posting');
```

takes ~10000ms to run. This is JUST to transfer the data in the message, not to run the worker logic itself.

You can read more on the postMessage transferList argument [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) and transferable types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable). It's important to note that the way your example is doing a timing comparison includes the web worker creation time, as well, but hopefully this gives a better idea for where a lot of that time is going and how it can be better worked around.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot more work between `t0` and `t1` compared to a simple `contains`. These extra steps include:

1. converting function -> string -> regex -> blob -> object URL
2. calling new worker -> parses object URL -> JS engine interprets code
3. sending web worked data -> serialized on main thread -> deserialized in worker (likely in memory struct that's copied actually, so not super slow)

You're better off creating the thread first, then continuously handing it data. It may not be faster but it won't lock up your UI.
Also, if you're repeatedly searching through the array may I suggest converting it into a map where the key is the array value and the value is the index.

e.g.
array `['apple', 'coconut', 'kiwi']` would be converted to `{ apple: 1, coconut: 2, kiwi:3 }`
searching through the map would occur in amortized normal time (fast), vs the array would be a linear search (slow as hell for large sets).

Comment: hm.. maybe you are right... I tried changing "promises.push(createWorker(element));" to "promises.push(createWorker());"  and "var value = e.data.includes(1);" to "var value = false;" and it is much faster... It seems copying the data to the thread is a problem... Could you provide some code how to pass the data later or can I share the same array without copying it?